# How to fetch Query String in XSLT file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

I have used XmlSource file for fetching dynamic menu items i also want to fetch the query string with two values in it.
I am getting error while defining &Name
Can somebody help me with this ?

```
<xsl:attribute name="NavigateUrl">
    <xsl:text>?Path=</xsl:text>    
    <xsl:value-of select="REPORT_PTH"/>

    <xsl:text>&Name=</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="REPORT_NM"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What's the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `&` with `&amp;` in the 5th line of the above code snippet.

In Xml, an ampersand (&) sign introduces an *entity*, a textual representation of an arbitrary character. This is usually used for special characters and for characters that would otherwise have a special meaning in Xml. As `&` has a special meaning (introducing entities), it always needs to be replaced with its entity form, namely `&amp;`.